# Freebase MQL Query for Movie title in german Language

Tags: freebase

i was trying to find a way how to query freebase for a Movie title in other than english language, i know Freebase has the data, i found a Query to return the german title with MQL, but how can i get all the other stuff like starring, imdv id etc..

I played around with the MQL Console and tried various settings, but either the properties are unknown or Freebase doesn't understand the Sheme anymore like "film/film due wrong settings, also a "lang":"de" doesn't make any changes, or it returns an empty result, my idea was to use the allies section but couldn't figure out how to filter this out...

thx for help

Comment: What is the query that got you closest to what you want?

Comment: Additionally, you need to at least proofread things well enough that they make sense.  imdv? Sheme? allies?  Even if you aren't a native English speaker, you should be able to copy acronyms and form your question well enough that someone can help you.